# hspace doesn't work. Depth

Tags: line-breaking

I need to locate my text in such way.
At first, I have some formula. There must be a little indent.

```
$bla-bla-bla$ \\
```

Then I have another formula, but the indent must be bigger.

```
   $bla-bla-bla$ \linebreak
```

An so on. It looks like the depth of the recursion.

```
   $bla-bla-bla$ \\ 

      $bla-bla-bla$ \\

          $bla-bla-bla$ \\

   $bla-bla-bla$  \\

   $bla-bla-bla$  \\

        $bla-bla-bla$  \\

        $bla-bla-bla$   \\
```

How can I do it? I try to use \hspace, but it works only at the beginning.

Comment: It seems to me as `algorithmic` could take place here. Are you writing an algoritm? What do you need this for?

Comment: it is just the picture of some call stack

Comment: Then I would recommend you to ask something like "How to display indented call stack" or similar, which points out your real target, and not the way you tried to solve it. That would allow the answers to better fit to your problem ;) See [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it once or twice, you can stay with something like the following. The empty `\hbox` makes sure that the following skip (`\quad` in this case) is not ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$f(4)=f(3)+f(2)=5$
\\\hbox{}
\quad $f(3)=f(2)+f(1)=3$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad $f(2)=f(1)+f(0)=2$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad\quad $f(1)=1$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad\quad $f(0)=1$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad $f(1)=0$
\\\hbox{}
\quad $f(2)=f(1)+f(0)=2$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad $f(1)=1$
\\\hbox{}
\quad\quad $f(0)=1$

\end{document}
```

Comment: do not use `\hbox` (as that behaves differently within a paragraph and between paragraphs and for that reason is not a user-level LaTeX command). Use either `\mbox{}` or better `\hspace*{1em}` etc.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Is there any other reason why not to use `\hbox{}` here other than that it's a TeX primitive? And `\hspace*{1em}` seems to me as "too long", even though it might be shorter than `\hbox{}\quad`, that's why I provided this alternative to David's answer.

Comment: LaTeX has a fairly consistent user-level context in that it ensures that all text-producing commands always ensure that they are in horizontal mode, ie within a paragraph, if necessary by starting one. A primitive like `\hbox`doesn't do this and that is giving users unnecessary surprises. For example if you would say, "use `\hbox{word}` to ensure that a certain word is not hyphenated" then this fails if it is the first word in a paragraph. Therefore those primitives should not be advertised as user-level commands and instead the LaTeX variants (in this case `\mbox`) should be suggested.

Comment: I therefore suggest you alter your solution to use the latter.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `\hspace*` as the star form avoids the space being discarded at the start of a line, but using an environment designed for laying out such expressions is probably preferable.  It is hard to say given your truncated example but perhaps `tabbing` or one of the `amsmath` alignments would be more suitable.